# How do I receive data the other activity?

Tags: java, android

I searched several posts here in stackoverflow and found none talking about migrating integers, tried several things but it did not work out. I'm a beginner and I probably missed something silly, but I can not see what it is.

I'm setting up a quiz, with several activities and I wanted to make a score that would be adding 1 point for each correct question of each activity.

Here is my code that is not working. If anyone can help me, I'm grateful right away.

Activity 1

```js
public class A_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView score;
int mScore = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_activity);

    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

}

public void onClickTrue(View v) {
    mScore++;
    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, B_Activity.class);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putInt("mScore", mScore);
    i.putExtras(params);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Activity 2 (reception)

```js
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b_activity);

    Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null){
            Bundle params = i.getExtras();

            if (params != null){
                String mScore = params.getString("mScore");

                }

        }

}
```

How I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `params.getInt(String key)` ?

Comment: This will work 100%:  String mScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("mScore", 0);

Comment: you are passing a int (params.putInt("mScore", mScore)) and expecting a string (params.getString("mScore")). You should use params.getInt("mScore")

Comment: "Please fix my code" is off-topic for Stack Overflow without an error message or other explanation as to why it is wrong.  Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: I Tried, but doesn't work. The system did not accept "String", it asked me to change to "int" and even then it does not work. I think I've tried all the combinations. I'm a beginner and I do not know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in second activity use this code

```
 Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(i!=null)
    {
        int a = i.getInt("mScore"); // in first activity you are putting integer values 
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(a), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, @Salman500. Good, thank you so much!!!, now it's working. Are you know how I use this like a variable global in my new activity?

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi, @Salman500. Are you know how I use this like a variable global in my new activity?

Comment: public class B_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Bundle b = null; // global 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_activity);


// and do whatever you want to do


    }

Answer (score 1):

When you put data into bundle you used `putInt`.
So, in another activity use `getIntExtra` method

```
String mScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("mScore", 0);
```